# javascript encoding issue with accented characters

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a page with UTF-8 header:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

And in the page I use the umbraco dictionary to fetch content in various languages.
When I print this in German on the page it appears fine:

```
<h1>@library.GetDictionaryItem("A")</h1>
```

resolves to:

`<h1>Ä</h1>` in German

However if I enter it via a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var a = "@library.GetDictionaryItem("A")";
  alert(a);
</script>
```

The alert prints:

```
&#228;
```

If I do

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var a = "Ä";
  alert(a);
</script>
```

The alert prints:

```
Ä
```

So what could explain this behaviour and how can I fix the alert?
As far as I can see everything is UTF-8 and the dictionary and the page encoding is fine. The problem happens within Javascript.

From what I can see from the table here, Javascript resolves the character into it's Numeric value. I used "escape, encodeUrl, decodeUrl" etc with no luck.

```
chr  HexCode  Numeric   HTML entity     escape(chr)  encodeURI(chr) 

ä    \xE4     &#228;    &auml;          %E4          %C3%A4
```

Comment: "Javascript resolves the character into its Numeric value" — No. The character reference will be generated by your server side code. It looks OK when you output it as HTML because the character reference has special meaning in HTML (but doesn't in JavaScript).

Comment: Okay so how can I get the alert to behave as if I typed it in?

Comment: That's (presumably) a umbraco dictionary problem and I've never heard of that before.

Comment: This has nothing to do with character encoding.

Comment: It could very well be an umbraco issue, but the dictionary works well everywhere in all languages and the alert also works well even in Japanese, Chinese, Arabic etc. The problem is only with accented characters within the javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(FWIW: Character entity `&#228;` is `ä`, not `Ä`.)

This has nothing to do with character encoding. You're outputting an HTML *entity* to a JavaScript string, and then asking the browser to display that JavaScript string without doing anything to interpret HTML (via `alert`). It's exactly as though you actually typed:

```
<h1>&#228;</h1>
```

...(which will show `ä` on the page), and

```
<script>
var a = "&#228;";
alert(a);
</script>
```

...which won't. The HTML entity isn't being used anywhere that understands HTML entities. `alert` doesn't interpret HTML.

But if you did this:

```
<script>
var a = "&#228;";
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = a;
document.body.appendChild(div);
</script>
```

...you'd see the character on the page, because we're giving the entity to something (`innerHTML`) that will interpret HTML. And so if you make that first line:

```
var a = "@library.GetDictionaryItem("A")";
```

...and then use `a` in an HTML context (as above), you'll get the `ä` in the document.

If you *always* get a decimal numeric character entity (like `&#228;`) from Umbraco, since those define unicode code points and JavaScript (mostly) uses unicode code points in its strings*, you can parse the entity easily enough:

```
function characterFromDecimalNumericEntity(str) {
    var decNumEntRex = /^\&#(\d+);$/;
    var match = decNumEntRex.exec(str);
    var codepoint = match ? parseInt(match[1], 10) : null;
    var character = codepoint ? String.fromCharCode(codepoint) : null;
    return character;
}
alert(characterFromDecimalNumericEntity("&#228;")); // ä
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/yagejucu/1)

* Why "mostly": JavaScript strings are made up of 16-bit "characters" that correspond to UTF-16 *code units*, not Unicode code points (you can't store a Unicode code point in 16 bits, you need 21). All characters from the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) fit within one UTF-16 code unit, but characters from the [Supplementary Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane), [Supplementary Ideographic Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Supplementary_Ideographic_Plane), [and so on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Code_point_planes_and_blocks) require *two* UTF-16 code units for a character. One of those characters will occupy two "characters" in a JavaScript string. The function above would fail for them. More in [the JavaScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) and [the Unicode FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

Comment: Yes that worked but I can't say I understand it fully.

I find that creating a div element and using the in built html parser to print out one character is far from elegant

Comment: @Nick: TJC is not really telling you how to fix your issue, but explaining what's happening underneath.  You probably need to read it over until you do understand it fully.  Then you can think about solutions.

Comment: @Nick: No, of course; I'm just demonstrating that the real issue here is that you're getting an HTML entity (`&#228;`), and so you need to have that interpreted in an HTML context for it to be rendered as `Ä`. I've just added something to the answer if you always get decimal numeric entities, and you want to use them in JavaScript and not in HTML.